# getting error for the use of "dash" in namespace

Tags: php

I have namespace issue with PHP where I want to use a directory that has dash in it:

```
test-library
```

and when I do this

```
use \test-library\myclass
```

I get an error for dash. Any idea how can I get around this

Comment: What's the exact error? What's the line causing the error?

Comment: it says its expecting semicolon in use \test-library\myclass

Comment: I guess I will just change directory name.

Comment: I repeat: What's the code in the line causing the error?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with every single PHP version. Just [php] is enough. Also, *of course* `-` is not a valid character in a label as it is the minus operator...

Answer (score 3):

Add a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
use \test-library\myclass;
```